# Geoprocessing results outside of defined extent

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, modelbuilder, geoprocessing, extents

I am running ArcGIS 10.2 Desktop

Several different models I have built and tested successfully previously are demonstrating the same problem. They appear to execute slightly to the South of the indented location.

All the tools work by taking several shapefiles, converting them to rasters as defined by an extent raster, and then doing some "stuff" to the rasters before outputting a single results raster.

The image shows one of the examples the red polyline file and the green polygon file should be processed within the boundaries of the blue raster. The actual result in black is slightly below.

I have checked the spatial reference of all the inputs and the data frame and they are all the same. So I am perplexed as to why this is happening.

As I said all the models work on other datasets that I have used. I have gone back and done some test runs and the models are fine. I suspect it is something to do with the input data but I don't know what to check for. I get no warning or error messages when running the models.

[image: Example of Problem]

Comment: Coding questions without code are impossible to answer. It doesn't help when the "blue raster" does not appear to exist.

Comment: @falcs Have you same projection?

Comment: I found that modification of spatial extent and cell size inside script are ignored by spatial analyst tools. I had to fix them manually in mxd

Comment: @Vince the blue rasters is the big light blue rectangle in the middle of the picture. This is not a coding question, as I said in the code works correctly in other cased and the problem occurs on many different pieces of code. It must be something to do with the input data.

Comment: @GeostoneMarten yes all the layers have the same projection

Comment: There's an *aqua* box, which 15% of the population will see as green. If you're going to name that color, be sure to include the large green component ("blue-green", "aqua"); either that, or use a blue color (0000FF RGB). Usability is a key component in mapping.  If your code doesn't work with some data, it's still the code's fault. Data is blameless.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looking for This subject [handling projections during analysis](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/guide-books/extensions/spatial-analyst/performing-analysis/handling-projections-during-analysis.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the tool was using the wrong extent raster. This seems to be a fault with ArcGIS because the input I provided was correct, and it was the the one that appeared in the log file. However, when I renamed another file the tool started using the raster specified rather than the one it had been using.

Comment: Sounds to me like this was a PEBCAK error.